# How to create html5 nav bar with hover effect images?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this good to work as a nav bar:

[html5 navbar with images](http://jsfiddle.net/AQbyC/86/)

But they just keep lining up ontop of each other, any suggestion on how to get them to align horizontally like a navbar should?

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/YKQq4/

I've used `inline-block` property instead of just `inline`.